# Remotely connecting a USB device

Tags: windows-7, usb, remote-access, hardware-virtualization

I need to "remotely" connect a USB device. I need to sync my PDA with my home computer when I only have physical access to my laptop.

I am able to use TeamViewer to remotely control the target computer, and to VPN into it.
Once, I found [USB over network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/) which seemed pretty useful but really expensive.

Do you know if there is any cheaper, possibly **free**, solution to my problem?

Seems that TeamViewer itself is unable to share hardware.

Thank you

[EDIT]

My final purpose is to use ActiveSync to synchronize PDA with desktop, mainly to establish a relationship the first time without physical access to computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you've already tried teamviewer & because you're using teamviewer for remote access I'm not sure this will work but if you could access your Home computer using Remote Desktop from the laptop then configuring the remote desktop client to have local resources access might work if the PDA only needs to be seen as a drive for syncing it to work.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313292 under the "How to gain access to local files" section it shows how to configure the client side for access to local resources.

Like I said not completely sure this would work or is even a viable option for you but it could be worth a shot.

Hope it helps,
Darren

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't apply to me. I need ActiveSync. ActiveSync needs USB. Editing post

Comment: RDP has supported attaching USB devices for a while now.